# Issue getting correct headers from Opera Mini

Tags: php, mobile, opera-mini

For all of our mobile sites we log all incoming requests to our pages via a PHP script. We get thousands of hits each day from Opera mini and we have been using the code snippet below to determine the correct user agent.

```
if (array_key_exists("X-OperaMini-Phone", $headers))
{
$ua= mysql_real_escape_string('Opera-').($headers["X-OperaMini-Phone"]);
}
else
```

{
    $ua = mysql_real_escape_string($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
    }

However, after running this for some time I find that in the vast majority of cases the X-OperaMini-Phone header is blank. Does the code above look correct? And if so, can you shed some light on why?

Answer (score 0):

It is more advisable to look for the string "Opera Mini" in the UA string while detecting Opera Mini. **X-OperaMini-Phone** header may not be reported by all devices. Refer here for details. http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/opera-mini-request-headers/

Comment: I do look at the UA string as per the code above? Not sure I understand the answer?

Comment: You need to look out for the string "Opera Mini" in the "User-Agent" header, not just look for all the headers.

Comment: But how would looking for the Opera Mini string in the User-Agent provide me with the actual underlying user agent, which is what I'm looking for

Comment: I've read the article on several occasions. That's how I know to check for the X-OperaMini-Phone header. My question is based on actual experience of trying to interrogate that header and finding that in the vast majority of cases, the header does not provide the relevant info

Comment: The article mentions, **Note that this header is only present if we have some reasonable evidence that our data is true.**